# can't enable freestyle

Tags: rendering, freestyle

I am checking all boxes but the freestyle outlines are not visible in the rendering.
I have tried different crease angles, butt/round profiles, but I cannot see anything.
Any bet on what it could be ?
thank in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use the compositor. First go to View layer properties and under freestyle check "As Render Pass".

[image]

Then go to the compositor and check "use Nodes". Mix the Freestyle and the image in the render layer node and connect it to the output.

[image]

Next to Mix is an button, activate it for the alpha channel otherwise the image might be lighter than wanted.